# Configuring a samba share

Tags: samba, smb, ubuntu-server

Ubuntu server 14.04

My head is full of networking stuff right now and I just can't get my head around samba. I need a share that allows read and write access to authenticated users only, with no home directories and all the users can modify other users' stuff. I need to know what parameters to set in /etc/smb.conf and how to properly add users.

Also, whenever I sudo Ubuntu goes `no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory` - this is apparently a samba related issue.

Comment: first off, for your loadparm problem, that usually indicates bad configuration. run `sudo testparm -s` and note any errors or warnings, or sections of your config document that are not displayed.

Comment: for the permissions, I recommend putting the authenticated users in the group users or smbusers. then go to your samba share root, and chown it so that the group is users or smbusers and give it permissions like 2774, which turns on SetGID. that means that new files and folders created with that dir will automatically take on the group ownership of the parent. that way your users will have their ownership checked by group when accessing another users objects. another option is the sticky bit, which may work perfectly in you. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_setuid_setgid_skicky_bit.htm

Comment: then configure the samba createmask and directorymask settings to have the same permissions as those you've applied to the filesystem.

Comment: I can't really see anything wrong [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxm9LVxEKx1gTFhTaEJudnJlLWs/edit?usp=sharing) I'm going to try and do the other stuff though.

Comment: ok, for your error, run `pam-auth-update` and uncheck "SMB password synchronization" if present. if not, you can probably uninstall libpam-smbpass, but I'd save that as a last ditch. source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214042